# Is $G/H$ isomorphic to $G'$ if there exists an homomorphism between $G$ and $G'$ and $H$ being a normal subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I have three questions :

I understand the first isomorphic theorem, which states that a homomorphic image of a group is isomorphic to the quotient group formed by the group $G$ and the kernel of group $G$.

$1$. Is this theorem only true for Kernel $K$, or for any normal subgroup of $G$ ?

Also, suppose there exists a homomorphism $\phi$ between $G$ and $G'$.
Let $$H = \{x \in G \; ; \; \phi(x) \in H'\}.$$
Then $H$ is subgroup of $G$. We can also show that given that $H'$ is normal in $G'$, $H$ is normal in $G$.
Here, there exists an homomorphism between $H$ and $H'$.

$2$. Is the function defining homomorphism between $G$ and $G'$ same as $H$ and $H'$ ?

From first isomorphism theorem, we can say, $G/K \cong G'$ and $H/K \cong H'$

$3$. Then Can I make this statement :
Given a group $G$, and subgroup $H$ of $G$, if there exists a homomorphism between $G$ and $G'$ with Kernel $K$ and $H'$ being a subgroup of $G'$, such that $G/K \cong G'$ and $H/K \cong H'$, then $H$ is normal in $G$ and $H'$ is normal in $G'$ ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, the kernel depends on the homomorphism in question, with a different homomorphism you'll have a different kernel. However, given any normal subgroup $H$, you can always find a homomorphism to some group whose kernel is $H$, namely, $\phi\colon G\to G/H$ is a surjective homomorphism with kernel $H$.

I don't quite understand your second question. I'm assuming you have a homomorphism $\phi\colon G\to G'$ and $H'\lhd G'$. If you are taking $H = \phi^{-1}(H')$, then $H$ is the kernel of
$$G\xrightarrow{\phi} G'\to G'/H',$$
hence it is normal. You can restrict $\phi$ to $H$ to get a surjective homomorphism $\phi\colon H\to H'$ and from the first isomorphism theorem, $H/K\cong H'$.

Lastly, your claim is not true. Simply take a subgroup $H$ which is not normal, and the identity map $G\to G$. Then the kernel $K$ is trivial, $G/K\cong G, H/K\cong H$ but $H$ is not normal.

Comment: Regarding first question, I understand that there will be a homomorphism between G and G/H.  My question is when H is just a normal subgroup and not kernel of G, then will there be an isomorphism between G/H and G'(homomorphic image of G) ?

Comment: @latus_rectum No, not in general. For example, consider a finite group, then $G/H$ and $G'\cong G/K$ need not even have the same cardinality. Also, it is possible that $G/H\cong G/K$ via some isomorphism, but this isomorphism need not be related to the given $\phi\colon G\to G'$, i.e., there may be an isomorphism, but it need not arise in some natural way from $\phi$.

Comment: And clarity regarding second question :: 
There exists a homomorphism between G and G' given by $\phi$.
And from mapping which I have mentioned in question, we have established that there exists a homomorphism between H(subgroup of G) and H'(subgroup of G').
My question is : Is this homomorphism also defined by using the same function $\phi$ or is it some other homomorphic function ?

Comment: @latus_rectum what is the mapping you mention? It should be the restriction of $\phi$ to $H$ as I have written in my answer and well, this is the only way we have to get from $H$ to $H'$.

Comment: In your answer, why you state that H is the kernel of homomorphism $\phi$ ? When I was asking the question, I considered H to be just a subgroup under G. 
What I am interested in is :: Between G and G', there is homomorphism $\phi$. Can subgroup inside the group can be homomorphic under some under function ?

I might be asking the wrong question. Maybe homomorphism between subgroups is possible only if it defined by the same homomorphic function which is there in between the groups. Thanks for your replies.

Comment: @latus_rectum well, if you have subgroups $H, H'$ of $G, G'$ respectively, then there can be a homomorphism between them, independent of $G, G'$ or any homomorphism between $G, G'$.